# Body erratic movement when impulse applied(Cocos2d-Box2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

Basically i am trying to apply impulse to a round body in a specific angle.
But the body moves in a erratic direction.
Can anyone please help me.

```
b2Vec2 v1 = bombbody->GetPosition();
b2Vec2 v2 = arrowPoint;//Value got from touch
b2Vec2 final = v2-v1;
float angle1 = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(atan2(final.y,final.x));
float factor = sqrt(final.x/PTM_RATIO * final.x/PTM_RATIO + final.y/PTM_RATIO * final.y/PTM_RATIO);
b2Vec2 ImpulseVector = b2Vec2(cos(angle1)*factor,sin(angle1)*factor);
b2Vec2 PointVector = bombbody->GetPosition();
bombbody->ApplyLinearImpulse(ImpulseVector,PointVector);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `b2Body::GetWorldCenter` for the second parameter of `b2Body::ApplyLinearImpulse`:

```
  b2Vec2 PointVector = bombbody->GetWorldCenter();
  bombbody->ApplyLinearImpulse(ImpulseVector,PointVector);
```

According to a [post at Box2D forum](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6539), the reason why `GetPosition` doesn't work with force is that the force works with the body's center of mass, which might not always be the same as its position.